# Plotting out Compass Bearing on iPhone screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, gps, coordinates

Ok so here is my question,

Let's say you have a bearing of 80 degrees. I would like to plot that out on the iPhone screen with a simple 10x10 square. Let's figure the top of the iPhone in portrait mode is North.

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

BTW - I don't want to use the following method:

```
CGAffineTransform where  = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(x_rounded));
[self.compassContainer2 setTransform:where];
```

I would like to plot out on the screen manually via setting the X -Y cords on the iPhone screen.

Comment: Why do you not want to just rotate the view as you have shown above?

Comment: Because that requires to have an even circle, and unfortunately the iPhone portrait size(320 x 460) does not make an even circle with the desired height I would like to have.

Comment: Why would you not just create a smaller view to the size/height you want? There is a lot of math that you have to do, if you want to draw the line yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float compass_bearing = 80.0;  // 0 = North, 90 = East, etc.

    CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 5.0, 5.0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,
        5.0 + 5.0 * cos((compass_bearing - 90.0) * M_PI / 180.0),
        5.0 + 5.0 * sin((compass_bearing - 90.0) * M_PI / 180.0));

    CGContextSetLineWidth(theContext, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(theContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(theContext, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(theContext);

    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Comment: This will do!. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds to me like what you want to accomplish should exist within the `drawRect` method of a custom view, and then this view would be added to your screen by whatever method you desired (i.e. storyboard or programmatically). Here is a possible implementation that you could use to draw a straight line from the center of the view based on some 'angle':

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Drawing code
    CGFloat angle = 0.0 /180.0 * M_PI ;

    //Set this to be the length from the center
    CGFloat lineDist = 320.0;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,  5.0);
    //Set Color
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    //Draw the line
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    //Move to center
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);

    //Draw line based on unit circle
    //Calculate point based on center starting point, and some movement from there based on the angle.
    CGFloat xEndPoint = lineDist * sin(angle) + self.frame.size.width/2;
    //Calculate point based on center starting point, and some movement from there based on the angle. (0 is the top of the view, so want to move up when your answer is negative)    
    CGFloat yEndPoint = -lineDist * cos(angle) + self.frame.size.height/2;

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xEndPoint, yEndPoint);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for! Thank you - I just combined both your answers together to achieve  what I am looking for.